# Store pig result to local file

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I run pig script do some aggerative operation, and output size is very small.

Now I run

```
hadoop fs -getmerge ...
```

separately.

Any way to let pig script dump the result into local file directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not worried about merging everything to a single file then you can use the copyToLocal command in grunt (http://wiki.apache.org/pig/Grunt):

```
grunt> copyToLocal <src> <dest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way is to embed Pig into Python or JavaScript. You may do something like this (in Python):

```
import os
from org.apache.pig.scripting import Pig

P = Pig.compile("PUT YOUR PIG CODE HERE")
hdfs_input = "YOUR HDFS INPUT"
hdfs_output = "YOUR HDFS OUTPUT"
local_output = "YOUR LOCAL OUTPUT"
result = P.bind({'in': input, 'out': hdfs_output}).runSingle()
os.system("hadoop fs -getmerge " + hdfs_output + " " + local_output)
```

and run the Python code by (for example)

```
pig -useHCatalog python_code.py
```