# Getting results of a pig script on a remote cluster

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a way to get the results of a pig script run on a remote cluster directly without STORE-ing them and retrieving them separately?

Comment: well you can add path of the input and output folders as a parameters

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? How would i then use these paths? You mean use a pig UDF of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use a pig parameters to run your scripts. For example:

```
example.pig

A = LOAD '$PATH_TO_FOLDER_WITH_DATA' AS (f1:int, f2:int, f3:int);
--# Do Something With Your Data, and get output
C = STORE ouput INTO '$OUTPUT_PATH'
```

Then you can run the script like:

```
pig -p "/path/to/local/file" -p "/path/to/the/output" example.pig
```

So to automate in BASH:

```
storelocal.sh
#!/bin/bash
pig -p '$PATH_TO_FILES' -p '$PATH_TO_HDFS_OUT' example.pig
hdfs dfs -getmerge '$PATH_TO_HDFS_OUT' '$PATH_TO_LOCAL'
```

And you can run it `./storelocal.sh /path/to/local/file /path/to/the/local/output`

Comment: well i want to run a script to a **remote** cluster and I want to receive the results back to the machine I invoked the pig script from (say client). STORE will store results to hdfs which i can then retrieve, but i was asking whether there is another way to send the results to the client without storing them to hdfs first.

Comment: Then there is no other way rather than to write Java or even simpler python UDF. Another way is to automate it with BASH. Here is a link to the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685418/store-pig-result-to-local-file